# SQLite, FTS, MATCH and separating text in a column

Tags: sqlite, match, full-text-search

I have an SQLite database with a virtual table "myTable" created using FTS4, with one column "myColumn" of text using `|` as a separating character.

I query this database with `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn MATCH 'out to';` and I'm getting hits with entries that look like `"...out|to..."` but with no "out to" substrings.

The same thing happens when I replace `|` with punctuation like `;`. (Note the SQLite docs make explicit that you can't use `_` as a separating character.)

Why is that and how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTS's default tokenizer drops any punctuation from the indexed data, and also from your input query. It would find a match for a entry "... out to ..." even if you query `MATCH 'out/to'`
The solution to this is using phrase searches, `MATCH '"out to"'` . It won't work if you wish to find those words in a record that does not have them in that order.